# How to bind "this" automatically while calling a function?

Tags: javascript

My example code:

```js
    var Person = (function () {
        var __sym = Symbol('Person');

        class Person {
            constructor(name) {
                this[__sym] = { name: name };
            }
            getName() {
                let _this = this[__sym];

                return _this.name;
            }
        }

        return Person;
    }());

    var person = new Person('Hermione');

    console.log(person.name); // undefined
    console.log(person.getName()); // Hermione
```

In this example, I'd use `__sym` as a key to assign to the *private data*.

My question is: How to bind `this[__sym]` to every method inside the Person class?

My real project:

```
let Chatwindow = (function () {
    let __sym = Symbol('Chatwindow');

    let __data = {};

    // for typo
    let __prop = {
        targetUserId: 'targetUserId'
    };

    __data.init = function (...args) {
        let _this = this[__sym];

        let options = args[0];

        // validating the type of 'options' and the properties...

        // just get what I need
        _this[__prop.targetUserId] = options[__prop.targetUserId];

        (async () => {
            let messages = await __data.getMessagesAsync.call(_this);

            // my goal:
            // let messages = await __data.getMessagesAsync();
        })();
    };
    __data.getMessagesAsync = function () {
        let _this = this;

        let promise = new Promise(function (done) {
            // create model before sending
            let model = { [__prop.targetUserId]: _this[__prop.targetUserId] };

            // sending...

            done();
        });

        return promise;
    };

    class Chatwindow {
        constructor() {
            this[__sym] = {};
        }
        set init(value) {
            return __data.init;
        }
        get init() {
            return (...args) => __data.init.call(this, ...args);
        }
    }

    return Chatwindow;
}());
```

Everytime I call a method, I have to use `call(_this)` function to bind the key, like this:

```
let messages = await __data.getMessagesAsync.call(_this);
```

After that, inside the `getMessagesAsync` method, I can assign to the private data using `this` property.

What I want to achieve: I want to bind all of the methods just one time inside the `init` method. How can I do that?

Something like this:

```
__data.getMessagesAsync.oncall = function () {
    // bind this with this[__sym]
};
```

Then,

```
__data.getMessagesAsync(); // no need to pass anymore
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered switching to Typescript? You'd be able to declare private properties, and the compiler will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: That's looks like a spaghetti code. Unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @minitauros Thanks! I will care.

Comment: @undefined My idea comes from: `this` data has some private data. To assign that data, I need a key. And the key is a Symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, using `function_name.bind(o)` allows you to create a new function whose context `this` is bound to the object `o`.

What you want is to create a new function:

```
__data.boundMessagesFunction = __data.getMessagesAsync.bind(_this);
```

Now you can call:

```
let messages = await __data.boundMessagesFunction();
```

Comment: You made me think about interface or abstract class. But it's still a good solution. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Make sure to check out @dark_gf response about arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrow functions, so you will be sure that context (this) will be same every time (this will be pointing to parent this no matter from where arrow function is called)

```
__data.getMessagesAsync = () => {
    let promise = new Promise((done) => {
        // create model before sending
        let model = { [__prop.targetUserId]: this[__prop.targetUserId] };

        // sending...

        done();
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But using this way, I still need `this[__sym][__prop.targetUserId]`